# How to generate an n-dimensional grid in python

Tags: python, numpy

I want to generate an n-dimensional grid.

For a 3D grid, I have the following working code (which creates a grid of 5X5X5 between (-1,1 )

```
import numpy as np
subdivision = 5
step = 1.0/subdivision
grid= np.mgrid[ step-1 : 1.0-step: complex(0, subdivision),
                step-1 : 1.0-step: complex(0, subdivision),
                step-1 : 1.0-step: complex(0, subdivision)]
```

I want to generalize this to n dimensions
so something like

```
grid = np.mgrid[step-1 : 1.0-step: complex(0,subdivision) for i in range(n)]
```

But this obviously doesnt work. 
I also tried

```
temp = [np.linspace(step-1 , 1.0-step, subdivision) for i in range(D)]
grid = np.mgrid[temp]
```

But this doesn't work either since `np.mgrid` accepts slices

Comment: What's the reason for using `complex`? With your 3D code I get 3x5x5x5. Is this intended?

Comment: @kazemakase From the documentation: "However, if the step length is a complex number (e.g. 5j), then the integer part of its magnitude is interpreted as specifying the number of points to create between the start and stop values, where the stop value *is inclusive*.". When a non-complex number is used, the stop value is exclusive.

Comment: @Evert Oh, thank you, I didn't know this. Seems like an obscure feature...

Comment: @kazemakase A keyword argument would be better, but that's not really an option here, so I guess someone came up with this option. Saves people from thinking to add half the step to the upper limit to make the normal case inclusive.

Comment: @Evert right, I guess that's the reason. Anyway, in this case it seems to make things worse as the OP had to explicitly adjust the upper limit. (Assuming it was intentional to make the lower and upper limit non-inclusive.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using `complex` you can define the step size explicitly using real numbers. In my opinion this is more concise:

```
grid= np.mgrid[ step-1 : 1.0: step * 2,
                step-1 : 1.0: step * 2,
                step-1 : 1.0: step * 2]
```

Dissecting above snippet, we see that `step-1 : 1.0: step * 2` defines a slice, and separating them by `,` creates a tuple of three slices, which is passed to `np.mgrid.__getitem__`.

We can generalize this to `n` dimensions by constructing a tuple of `n` slices:

```
n = 3
grid= np.mgrid[tuple(slice(step - 1, 1, step * 2) for _ in range(n))]
```

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by [kazemakase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45583668/1714410), you should replace the "short hand" slicing notations `step-1 : 1.0-step: complex(0,subdivision)` with an explicit call to [`slice`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/slice), and then combine it in a "`tuple` generator":

```
D = 6
grid = np.mgrid[tuple(slice(step-1, 1.0-step, complex(0,subdivision)) for i in range(D))]
```

Results with a 6D grid.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`meshgrid`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) and [`linspace`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html) to do what you want.

```
import numpy as np
X1, X2, X3 = np.meshgrid(*[np.linspace(-1,1,5),
                           np.linspace(-1,1,5),
                           np.linspace(-1,1,5)])
```

For many dimensions, you can do

```
D = 4
subdivision = 5
temp = [np.linspace(-1.0 , 1.0, subdivision) for i in range(D)]
res_to_unpack = np.meshgrid(*temp)
assert(len(res_to_unpack)==D)
```